# Tortoise SVN + Unreal Commander

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, windows-explorer, tortoisecvs, total-commander

I'm using Unreal Commander as a free alternative for total commander(win os). I've chosen to show native icon's and context menu and for tortoise cvs everything was fine. Since I started using Tortoise SVN I don't see it's icons on files and folders, and also if I left click on them I don't see SVN in context menu(still see CVS). But I can see all this stuff in usual win explorer. Does anyone have common situations or ideas what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a 64-bit OS, and Unreal Commander is a 32-bit app, make sure you install the 32-bit version of Tortoise SVN *in addition* to the 64-bit one.

You need to install both versions if you are going to use both types of app with it. (You always need the 64-bit version, at least if you want it to work with Windows Explorer and other 64-bit file managers.)

Off-topic: If you are in this situation, it's also worth noting that it's quite difficult to make a 32-bit file manager show the real view of a 64-bit machine (without also potentially breaking third-party add-ons), since 32-bit processes see a virtual view of the filesystem. (They can turn it off within their process, but that may then break parts of them or other components they load/run which require it or now see a conflicting view compared to the thing that launched them and the arguments it passed.)

Answer (score 0):

[SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) and [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) are both version control systems but are pretty apart and don't mix. Usually windows clients connect a folder on your hardisk to a repository and will display information there based on the repo info compared with your local working copy. If you had a connection to a CVS it is not normal to show anything while using SVN as is totally another system.